# Immutable classes in java

Tags: java, immutability

Is it required to make the fields of an Immutable class `private` as if they are marked as `final` , can not be changed ?
I mean isn't it enough to just mark the fields as `final` ?

(I know that it's not necessary for an immutable class to have final fields but it's advisable to have it for compile time check for the class internally.)

Comment: The member fields might have their own mutator methods, so you don't want those to be exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having private variables accessed through getters gives you more freedom with the implementation of the class. You can, for example, replace a trivial getter with an implementation which calculates or retrieves the value on access or caches the result.

Another reason to keep fields as private even when they are final is when the field is a mutable object. In that case the object can be changed even though it is final which is usually not what you want. Here is an example of a presumably immutable class with a public final field of the mutable [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class.

```
 class DateHolder {
      public final Date date;
      DateHolder(Date date) {
           this.date = date:
      }
 }

 // ...

 DateHolder holder = new DateHolder(Date.now());

 // this doesn't work because date is final:
 //holder.date = new Date(2013, 11, 23);

 // but this works even though date is final:
 holder.date.setYear(2013);
```

Comment: I got it. combining this answer and Boris the Spider's answer makes it more clear to me. To keep the fields private and getters to return immutables. Thanks !

Answer (score 7):

No this is not enough.

Consider this example:

```
final class ImmutableClass {
    private final List<String> data;

    public ImmutableClass(final List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

This class is `final` so cannot be extended. It's `data` field is `final` so cannot be changed after it is assigned.

**But**:

```
final ImmutableClass immutableClass = new ImmutableClass(data);
immutableClass.getData().add("Some other value");
```

Oops.

So to make a class truly immutable all fields should also **be immutable classes**, or **have defensive copies**.

For example, to correct the issues about you would need to do this:

```
final class ImmutableClass {
    private final List<String> data;

    public ImmutableClass(final List<String> data) {
        this.data = new ArrayList<>(data);
    }

    public List<String> getData() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(data);
    }
}
```

And this only works because **`String` is immutable**. If you had, for instance, a `List<Date>` you would also need to copy the individual `Date` objects.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: and I think with refelction api you can change content of data field at runtime?

Comment: @KickButtowski with reflection you can change the value of `Boolean.TRUE` to `false`. The only way to protect against reflection is to use a `SecurityManager`. Hence, in most cases, the effects of reflection are ignored.

Comment: oh k but the book that I'm reading says different, but thank you . can you add some info to your answer about it if u think it is relevant plz?

Answer (score 1):

`final` fields can only be assigned to from within the constructor. Therefore, making fields `final` is enough to make them immutable after construction. Assigning pointers to mutable objects to them is a different story.

Comment: That different story would be the more interesting one to talk about.

Comment: `final` fields can also be initialized at declaration. Also I agree with Philipp. Leaving out the "interesting" part makes this a non-answer.